# ASP.NET MVC5 Application w/ AspNet Identity / OWIN calls SQL Server view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS too often

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm a SQL Server DBA working on a very small database storing data for an application that I have been told is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

The application has a minimal number of users, the database is small, and I believe the application contains no custom SQL. In other words all database access is driven by the framework.

The application performance is dismal with simple operations taking up to 1 minute elapsed time. I can only look at the database performance which is excellent, except for 1 issue. The application is issuing the following query approximately 73 times per second.

```
(@Table nvarchar(11))
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table
```

I strongly suspect that this is contributing to the poor performance. However, the developers have no clue as to where this statement is coming from in the application. Any thoughts on this? I have searched for an answer and found one, but the developers insist that it is really old and not applicable.

Here is an update from the developer:

- .NET MVC application using Entity Framework 6 with Database First development.
- Repository pattern, where each entity instantiates the database context which inherits from IdentityDbContext.
- Repository objects handle CRUD operations, and more complex Linq to Entity methods that return entity domain objects (Model in Mvc). Repositories are injected (NInject) into the service. Service classes make calls to one or more repositories, and apply more complicated business logic to expose methods to be called by controllers. The domain objects are mapped (Automapper) to DTO objects for use in the controllers.
- Controllers (mvC) inject the services and perform logic required by the UI, and return ActionResult objects or ViewModels, for the most part, which are in turn called from cshtml pages (mVc).
- I'm wondering if something could be slightly off within the OnModelCreating method in the Context class, and that somehow causes something within the EF framework to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA looking for the correct column name?

** UPDATED **
We discovered that the nvarchar(11) parameter being passed is AspNetUsers, the table name used for AspNet Identity user login functionality.

So, this is not an EF problem, but these SQL queries are being generated from within the Asp.Net Identity functionality or OWIN middleware.

Comment: We would need more specific information about your app to be able to offer any suggestions. To be making a query like that one would expect an ORM of some sort (a bad one!).

Comment: Yes.   The .NET SqlClient gets result metadata from the TDS network stream, and wouldn't be querying the catalog views.

Comment: `@Table nvarchar(11)` is a very odd definition given that `sysname` used for object names is typically a synonym for `nvarchar(128) not null`. You (or the developers) might have to break out dotPeek, .NET Reflector or some other tool to inspect the application and its libraries to figure out from where these requests are originating.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is what I received from the developer:

Comment: Hook up a profiler to trace the `RPC` calls and see exactly what parameter *value* it's called with. The `NVARCHAR(11)` strongly suggests that what's being passed here is actually a constant -- a table name of exactly 11 characters long, which has its length inferred as such. This might give further hints on what's going on.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code from the developer, but I understand this is likely not possible. It almost sounds as if the developer has an Entity Framework model that represents a table in the database and that is in the repository. It is also possible that there is a library being used that is attempting to gather some metadata about a table. There are just too many possibilities without seeing the code to know what the culprit is.